# fancybox3 close button issue in electron app

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, fancybox-3

FIRST I understand that the close button not showing is common asked question. I have looked over most of the posts for a solution. However, none of which are helping, so this may be an electron based issue.

My team and I are creating an electron app. The main page of the app is html based with css and js. Fancybox 3 works as desired, EXCEPT the close button on the top right of the white box. When running the app, clicking the button for the fancybox simple message pop up works but the close button doesn't show. However, the functionality is there, I can click the area and it close.

The HTML front page section. - The 'about' is the button linking the fancybox.

```
<p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100"><a id="about" href="javascript:;" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-md smoothscroll">About</a></p>
```

javascript for button

```
$("#about").on('click', function() {
  $.fancybox.open(
    '<div class="message"><h2>OATES User Interface</h2><p>Welcome to the OUI! (pronounced weeee!, like the Frenchies)</p></div>');
});
```

screenshot for reference. [missing close button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL3w9.png)

Oddly enough, when I take this two blocks of code out and place them into a template index.html and JS script and open with a browser, the close button shows and works fine. 
[Seen HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIss3.png)

I have tried to solve this using another script for the JS but I am not familiar with fancybox enough to customize the simple message pop up box. This is what I tried, but it does not read the html correctly and places the close button at the top right of the appication window.

```
$("#about").on('click', function() {

  $.fancybox.open({
    showCloseButton : 'true',
    tpl : '<div class="message"><h2>OATES User Interface</h2><p>Welcome to the OUI! (pronounced weeee!, like the Frenchies)</p>'
  });
});
```

[Look HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZp0a.png)

IF anyone has experience with Fancybox3 inside electron or can spot what I am doing wrong with my attempted solution to get the HTML to show properly, please let me know. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bro, if the button doesnt appear and if you can still activate its functionality, possibly it might be CSS issue. Can you inspect element on that area and see if you have the problem with relative path for that close image or z-index issue?

Comment: Why do you use `tpl` attribute? It should be `src`, see docs.